# Mockito initialize list of mock object behaviour

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I ran into this problem when writing unit tests and took me a while to fix it. But still, I would like to understand what caused the discrepant behaviour:

1) Using Arrays.asList()

```
@Mock SomeClass obj;
List<SomeClass> list = Arrays.asList(obj);
```

This method doesn't work. It creates a list of size 1, with a null obj inside.

2) Adding mock during setup

```
@Mock SomeClass obj;
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
@Before
public void setup() {
    list.add(obj);
}
```

This method works.

I'm just curious are the differences between the two methods, which might have caused one method to work but not the other?

Comment: Request for clarification: does my answer meet your question?

Answer (score -1):

The difference is based on the fact that the annotation @Mock  has *context*. What I mean is: just putting an annotation somewhere into your source code isn't enough. You have to understand how exactly the annotation works.

And this mockito annotation is based on the various phases that the Junit framework relies on. The @Before method is executed every time before another @Test method gets executed.

So in your first snippet, that code gets run once, initially when the test class itself gets initialized. And at that point, the @Mock annotation hasn't done its magic. Therefore that code simply adds a null to your list.

So basically there is a misconception on your end. You assume that there is only the scope of the annotation that matters. But things are more complicated. This annotation relies on specific temporal aspects of the underlying framework.

The real answer is: whenever you encounter annotations, you have to study their documentation extremely carefully, as they are much more than just some Java language keyword.